# Using a RequireJS and Backbone utility library

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

We have a set of projects that all use RequireJS and Backbone, these projects have a common utility library backend that also use these frameworks. We currently have a need to use the same library backend but in another website that isn't using RequireJS or Backbone.

I was wondering what was the best way of using RequireJS and Backbone when they are not defining the overall framework of the website. I was thinking of making jQuery plugin interfaces to the internal code somehow but overall it seems rather messy.

I'd also like to point out that I inherited this code base and am not an expert on many of these web technologies.

Thank you for any insight.

This is what our structure looks like for one of our projects:

```
index.html
css/
    styles.css
js/
    lib/
        utility_library/
            our_utilities.js
    page/
    model/
    view/
    app.js
    main.js
    router.js
```

In a rough sense anyway. So the main.js would have references to the files in the utilities_library folder and RequireJS is used in the index.html to load up the main.js which starts everything as expected for a RequireJS project.

However the structure the new project we're looking to include the utilities library into is something more like this:

```
index.html
jquery.js
jquery_ui.js
css/
    styles.css
js/
    app_logic.js
```

I'm keeping it fairly simple here but that's the essence of it. So all the logic and startup code is handled in the index.html file and app_logic.js file. I'm not sure how best it is to then bring in the utility library code when it's all packaged up in RequireJS and Backbone.

Comment: I think you should provide more information about how the current code is structured and things you have tried/planning to try. I think it's very hard to answer in some generic terms. You can use shim to add non-amd libraries. There is also RequireJS's define: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define, but you have probably seen that. Looking forward to your reply.